# glsl shader in/out variable packing

Tags: opengl, glsl

Does the order and/or size of shader in/out variables make any difference in memory use or performance? For example, are these:

```
// vert example:
out vec4 colorRadius;

// tess control example:
out vec4 colorRadius[];

// frag example:
in smooth vec4 colorRadius;
```

equivalent to these:

```
// vert example:
out vec3 color;
out float radius;

// tess control example:
out vec3 color[];
out float radius[];

// frag example:
in smooth vec3 color;
in smooth float radius;
```

Is there any additional cost with the second form or will the compiler pack them together in memory and treat them exactly the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler *could* pack these things together. But it doesn't have to, and there's little evidence that compilers commonly do this. So the top version will at least be no slower than the bottom version.

At the same time, this is more of a micro-optimization. So unless you know that this is a bottleneck, just let it go. It's best to write clear, easily understood code and optimize it when you know where your problems are, than to optimize it not knowing if it's going to be a concern.

Comment: In general I agree with the "optimize bottlenecks" philosophy, but at the same I have learned to try to optimize as much as possible as I write, as long as it doesn't adversely effect legibility.

Comment: @atb: It's impossible to "optimize as you write" because it's next to impossible to assess all the different kinds of side effects of ones code. Also premature optimization will very likely put you into a dead end if you find by profiling, that you'd better optimize something different, but your early "optimizations" need to be completely rewritten to do this.